# Flow huge amount of images from memory to Keras generator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train keras model with very large number of images and labels. I want to use the model.fit_generator and somehow flow the input images and labels from memory because we prepare all the data in memory, after the image is loaded. The problem is that we have plenty of large images that we then clip into smaller size and provide it like that to the model. We need a for loop inside a While loop.
Something like this:

```py
While True: 
    for file in files: #lets say that there are 500 files (images)
        image = ReadImage (file)
        X = prepareImage(image) # here it is cut and prepared in specific shape
        Y = labels
        yield X[batch_start:batch_end],Y[batch_start:batch_end]
```

After it yields the last batch for the first image we need to load the next image in the for loop, prepare the data and yield again in the same epoch. For the second epoch we need again all the images. The problem here is that we prepare everything in memory, from 1 image we create millions of training data and then move to next image. We cannot write all the data to the disk and flow_from_directory, since it would require plenty of disk space.

Any hint?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You coded the solution in your own questoin.

Comment: The code will be providing X[batch_start:batch_end] and Y[batch_start:batch_end] to the training and the for loop will load the second image and provide batch_start+batch_size:batch_end+batch_size, even though it did not finish with the first image and all the batches.

Also, how can we split the X,Y into train and test data before the training?